# Execute Monos sequentially/parallel

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have this situation:

```
Mono<List<String>> resultAMono = listA();
Mono<Void> resultBMono = loadB(resultAMono.block());
Mono<Void> resultCMono = loadC();
```

I want to execute resultAMono sequentially, and the resultBMono and resultCMono parallelly, because resultBMono depends of the result of resultAMono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `block` here. In reactive you need to build a flow combining different operators

```
Mono<Void> res = resultAMono
        .flatMap(a -> Flux.merge(loadB(a), loadC()).then());
```

We are using `Flux.merge` here because both `loadB` & `loadC` return `Mono<Void>` and we don't need results.

In case results are needed `Mono<B> loadB(A a)` & `Mono<C> loadC()` we can use `Mono.zip` to resolve publishers in parallel.

```
Mono<Tuple2<B, C>> res = resultAMono
        .flatMap(a -> Mono.zip(loadB(a), loadC()));
```

Both `Flux.merge` & `Mono.zip` subscribes to publishers eagerly.